# Laravel 5: assertSeeText() and html entities

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I'm using PHP Faker to generate random data (using factories) in the database and sometimes it generates apostrophes.

In my test, I use `assertSeeText()`.
The problem is that when the tested string contains special characters such as apostrophes, these characters are converted to html entities in the view so the assertion is false.

```
$siteShow = factory(Site::class)->create();
$this->get('admin/site/'. $siteShow->id_site)
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertSeeText($siteShow->name)
        ->assertSeeText($siteShow->address)
```

**Example case when the assertions fail:** `$siteShow->name` equals `O'Neil`. It fails because in the view it appears as `O&#039;Neil`.

My question is: how do I make it so that the assertion is true in both cases: the name in the view is `O'Neil` or `O&#039;Neil`? I would like the solution to handle any html entity if possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this problem does not exist in laravel 7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution. As my views are generated by Blade using the `{{ ... }}` syntax, the text is escaped and passed through `htmlspecialchars()` and if I'm correct, more especially through the [`e()` helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L574). So I just did the following and it works:

```
$siteShow = factory(Site::class)->create();
$this->get('admin/site/'. $siteShow->id_site)
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertSeeText(e($siteShow->name))
    ->assertSeeText(e($siteShow->address))
```

Comment: tl;dr Taylor Otwell: escaping the text sequence is the responsibility of the test designer.  https://github.com/laravel/framework/pulls?q=is%3Apr+assertseetext+is%3Aclosed

Answer (score 6):

SystemGlitch's answer didn't work for me  and I think the  best way is to use the second boolean parameter for `assertSeeText` and `assertSee` to disable escaping

```
$siteShow = factory(Site::class)->create();
$this->get('admin/site/'. $siteShow->id_site)
    ->assertSeeText($siteShow->name,false)
    ->assertSeeText($siteShow->address,false)
```

Comment: you are answering the wrong question. This person had an opposite problem. Your question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037805/laravel-7-assertsee-and-html-entities