# Laravel 7: assertSee() and html entities

Tags: phpunit, laravel-7

In my test, I use assertSee().

```
    $message = '<h1>Header</h1>';
    $response = $this->get($url);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertSee($message);
```

The problem is that when the `$message` contains html entities then the assertion gets false.

I know there is an `e()` helper to do convert html entities in $message but now I need the opposite.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

->assertSee(...) is [changed](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-see) in Laravel 7, now it has a second parameter

```
$response->assertSee($value, $escaped = true);
```

Just set it to `false`.

Documentation says:

> This assertion will automatically escape the given string unless you pass a second argument of false: